# How to Pass Iterator as Function Parameter in C++

Tags: c++, templates, vector, parameters, iterator

I'm writing my own C++ vector class and I want to be able to pass an iterator as a function parameter to my reverse() function, so that I can do something like

```
vector<int> scores{5,8,89,32};
reverse(scores.begin(), scores.end());
```

instead of

```
...
scores.reverse(); 
or 
reverse(scores)
```

I'm able to do the later with this code

```
template<typename T>
void reverse(vector<T> &orig) {
    //Reverse the elements of the array
    auto begin = orig.begin();
    auto end = --orig.end();    //Move the iterator 1 place back to keep within range

    while (begin < end) {

    std::swap(*begin, *end);

    begin++;
    end--;
    }
}
```

But when I do this

```
template<typename T>
void reverse(vector<T>::iterator begin, vector<T>::iterator end) {

    while (begin < end) {

        std::swap(*begin, *end);

        begin++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
error: expected ')' before 'begin'
```

What am I doing wrong, please?

Thank you.

Comment: I stumbled into some more issues: 1. Even with the fix of @NutCracker I got complaints because the type deduction didn't work as expected. After cheating a bit to skip the deduction... 2. Your `reverse()` has U.B. You access `end` but `end` may be one past end of storage. So, I fixed the iteration in loop. This is my fixed sample: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f78dbc91d86dd2ad). (However, @NutCracker nailed the primary issue of your question. Hence, I don't add my findings as answer.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was supposed to add the template type when I call the reverse function. I did not. Just did and it worked after I added @NutCracker suggestion. It works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void reverse(typename std::vector<T>::iterator begin, typename std::vector<T>::iterator end)
{...}
```

Without `typename` compiler cannot determine whether `iterator` is a member or type. So compiler assumes it is a member.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just did that and got this error:
..\main.cpp:37:39: error: no matching function for call to 'reverse(my::vector<int>::iterator, my::vector<int>::iterator)'
 my::reverse(scores.begin(), scores.end());                                       ^

..\bucket.h:230:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
..\main.cpp:37:39: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
 my::reverse(scores.begin(), scores.end());

Comment: @delivite I suggest you remove `using namespace std;` from your code. And add `std::` in front of everything that comes from the standard namespace. Let me know if this helped you.

Comment: I don't have using namespace std; in my code. I put my class in my:: namespace. That explains my::vector

Comment: I just found the problem for this last error. Thanks a lot. It works now. I've checked the green mark for this post. Thanks again.

Comment: @delivite glad I could help